# Extracting Address numbers in a Block Reference from autocad

Tags: autocad-map

I have an autoCad file of a subdivision and I want to extract the addresses from it. However, when I export the layer to a SHP, it loses any information it had about the actual addresses. The addresses are stored as a Block Reference Layer.

Usually, I can use Explode or Burst to break up the layer and then export. However, those two options are making AutoCad crash instead.

Does anyone have any recommendations on other ways to obtain the data? I'd rather not enter it all manually into ArcMap.

Edit:
**Solutions Tried**

1) I tried using the Import Cad Annotation tool and got an Error 000278 and 000016. This looked to be, maybe, due to an extent error which I've seen before when using the generated GDB's we get for these jobs. I made a new GDB just for the cad file to try to work around the extent issue and re-ran the tool. ...Only to get the same two errors. I am allowing the tool to create its own feature class but the error still occurs.

2) I added the annotation via Add Data and then right clicked and using Import Cad Annotation. This produced the same two errors.

3) In AutoCad 2012, I used WBLOCK to create a new cad file with ONLY the layer I wanted (Address). This ended up changing the data from an annotation layer to a CAD point file. Copy CAD Feature layer. This finally produced the closest result to what I wanted, a feature class with an attribute that had the address numbers in it.

Comment: Convert to annotations. Add geometry attributes like centroid. Create xy layer, and to shapefile.

Comment: While this didn't work (see above), it did help guide me to an option that did work. So thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AutoCad 2012, I used WBLOCK to create a new cad file with ONLY the layer I wanted (Address). This ended up changing the data from an annotation layer to a CAD point file. Copy CAD Feature layer. This finally produced the closest result to what I wanted, a feature class with an attribute that had the address numbers in it.